# SWAP size for a oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, swap

When I create a database with Oracle dbca tool, Oracle reserve 2Go of swap. I would find the location of this value in the configuration files to change it, because it's too much.

Could you help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

dbca doesn't have influence to swap size.
You mean maybe SGA or block cache?

Generally the `alter system` command is for tuning oracle parameters and they are stored in memory and in the related (s)pfile. http://orafaq.com/node/5